# 'Expecting colon' error in SOQL query when not using a variable

Tags: apex, soql

In the Anonymous Window of the developer console, I am attempting to execute the following:

```
System.debug(
    JSON.serialize([
        SELECT OpportunityLineItemSchedule.Revenue, OpportunityLineItemSchedule.ScheduleDate, OpportunityLineItemSchedule.OpportunityLineItem.TotalPrice, OpportunityLineItemSchedule.OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Id, OpportunityLineItemSchedule.OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.CloseDate, OpportunityLineItemSchedule.OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Amount
        FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule
        WHERE OpportunityLineItemSchedule.OpportunityLineItem.Opportunity.Amount != OpportunityLineItemSchedule.OpportunityLineItem.TotalPrice
    ])
);
```

I receive this error:

```
Line: 5, Column: 78
expecting a colon, found 'OpportunityLineItemSchedule.OpportunityLineItem.TotalPrice'
```

I understand this error typically pops up when one is attempting to use a variable in a query. However, I am not: I am using standard fields. Why am I receiving this error?

Comment: Are you sure it's an error in the query itself? I think it might be an issue with `JSON.serialize()` instead (no idea on how to fix that if it is the case). Can you try debugging the query without serializing it?

Comment: Refer this knowledge article by Salesforce: [Field to field comparison in WHERE clause of SOQL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187460&type=1)

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a field reference on the right side of a filter; SOQL, while similar to SQL, is definitely **not** SQL.

The following example is also illegal:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM Opportunity
WHERE Account.Name = Name
```

If you need to compare two fields together, you need to make a custom formula field, or query the records (potentially *all* of them), and compare them to each other. Assuming I remember correctly, the Schedule objects don't support custom fields, including formulas.

Note that any way you go about it, you're looking at a *full table scan*, so expect problems if you have a large number of records. You might want to narrow down your search via other techniques (such as filtering on an account name or something).